# Identical random permutations sequence for two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to do random permutation of columns in dataframe, but I need this permutation to be identical for both dataframes.

Right now I am having this

```
 X_train = X_train.sample(frac=1, axis=1) 
 X_test = X_test.sample(frac=1, axis=1)
```

This creates two different permutations, but I need the same permutation of columns for both `X_train` and `X_test`, e.g unison shuffle.

Thanks!

Comment: How about fixing the `random_state`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [sample()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html) method takes in a `random_state` that sets the seed for the random number generator. This should yield the same "random numbers" in both cases.

```
fixed_seed = 111
 X_train = X_train.sample(frac=1, axis=1, random_state =fixed_seed  ) 
 X_test = X_test.sample(frac=1, axis=1, random_state =fixed_seed )
```

Comment: It does not always work, I did this, but sometimes sequences differ

Comment: maybe the fact that i use random states in other operations gives this effect

Comment: Which other operations are using random_state?

Comment: I also subsample columns before
X_train = X_train.sample(subsample, axis=1)
X_test = X_test.sample(subsample, axis=1)

Comment: That could be the issue. Try fixing the state for those as well. So it becomes a fixed seed flow